# What does the set of rows is orthonormal means?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

I have this problem:

> [image]

What does the set of rows of the given matrix is orthonormal means? especially that our matrix is not a square matrix and so it is not an orthogonal matrix. Could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Let the rows be $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$.  The rows being orthonormal means that given any $i,j$ you have $v_i\cdot v_j = 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: And how this will help me in the solution? how is this related to the transpose of a matrix @JMoravitz

Comment: Recall that $(A^TA)^2 = A^TAA^TA$.  Now, consider $A^T(AA^T)A$ and look at the calculation for $AA^T$ more carefully.  What was the $i$'th row, $j$'th column entry of $AA^T$ written in terms of the rows of $A$ and dot products?  What then do you notice about $AA^T$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I have noticed that $AA^T$ is always the identity in our case .... but I do not know how to prove this rigorously ..... could you help me in this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $(A^TA)^2 = A^TAA^TA = A^T(AA^T)A$

Now, let us inspect $AA^T$ in more detail.

Recall that the definition of matrix multiplication is that the $i$'th row $j$'th column entry of a matrix $(AB)$ is $(AB)_{i,j}=\sum\limits_k (A)_{i,k}(B)_{k,j}$.  That is, reworded, the $i$'th row $j$'th column entry of the product of two matrices is the dot product of the corresponding $i$'th row from the matrix on the left with the corresponding $j$'th column from the matrix on the right.

Now, recognize that we were told that the rows of $A$ are orthonormal and the columns of $A^T$ are just the rows of $A$ transposed.

As such, it follows that the $i$'th row $j$'th column entry of $(AA^T)$ will be the dot product of the $i$'th and $j$'th rows of $A$, which because the rows are orthonormal results in $1$ in the case that $i=j$ and results in $0$ otherwise by the definition of what it means to be orthonormal.  That is to say, we will have $1$'s along the diagonal and $0$'s everywhere else.  We finally recognize this result as simply being the identity matrix.

This gives us that $(A^TA)^2 = A^T(AA^T)A = A^TIA = A^TA$, proving the claim.